# Trying to access JWT Authenticated Users content gives 401 in laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, redux, jwt

I have React frontend and Laravel Backend Application which authenticates user using JWT. The login process is working properly and I can get the authenticated user with the me function of JWT. But now when I try to access contents based on the authenticated user, I get 401 error. I'm adding my react axios function and also my laravel controller that has the function which is giving the error. Please point out what am I doing wrong on it. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

React axios function:

```
export const fetchMyApplications = () => {
    return async dispatch => {
        const url = `/auth/my-applications`;
        var formdata = new FormData();
        const token = getCookie("userToken");

        const response = await api
            .get(
                url, 
                {
                    headers: {
                      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                    }
                }
            )
            .then(res => {
                return res;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return error.response;
            });
        
        dispatch({
            type: "FETCH_MY_APLICATIONS",
            payload: response
        });
    };

}
```

Laravel controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\Application;

class ApplyController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        \Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', \App\Applicant::class);
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' =['personalDetails']]);
    }

    public function myApplications(){
        try {
            $user = auth()->userOrFail();
            $applications = Application::where('applicant_id', $user->applicant_id)->with('course')->get();
            return response()->json(['applications'=> $applications], 200);
        }catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\UserNotDefinedException $e) {
            return response()->json(['status'=> false, 'errors'=> 'Unauthenticated User'], 401);
        }
    }

}
```

Auth Config:

```
'defaults' => [
   'guard' => 'api',
   'passwords' => 'users',
],
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

Postman Checking Logged In User:
[image: Checking Logged In User]

Postman Trying to get applications of logged in user:

[image: Trying to get applications of logged in user gives error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. Actually it was not with my code, rather it was apache configuration on linode server. I added authorization header to the apache config file and it worked.